# Sort Sitemap URLs By Last Modified Date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML 1.0 sitemap like this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://localhost/page-1</loc>
<lastmod>2020-09-21</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost/page-2</loc>
<lastmod>2020-09-23</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Here's the XSLT 1.0 stylesheet for the above XML sitemap:

```
<xsl:template match="sm:urlset">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Last Modified</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<xsl:for-each select="sm:url">
<tr>
<xsl:variable name="pos">
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="loc">
<xsl:value-of select="sm:loc" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lastmod">
<xsl:value-of select="sm:lastmod" />
</xsl:variable>
<th>
<xsl:value-of select="$pos" />
</th>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="$loc" />
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="$lastmod" />
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</tbody>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I sort the sitemap by `sm:lastmod` (last modified) date? Please note that I'm using Microsoft Edge Version 87.0.664.60 (Chromium Embedded Framework based) at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3 and higher order functions (Saxon 10 all editions, Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 PE and EE, Saxon JS 2) support the most compact would be `xsl:for-each select="sort(sm:url, (), function($url) { $url/sm:lastmod })"`.

Otherwise of course use `xsl:sort` inside of the `for-each`: `<xsl:sort select="sm:lastmod"/>`.

Comment: Can you show me where should I add your code in the above XSL stylesheet? I have tried both methods that you have mentioned, but since I'm an amateur at this, it's not working for me so I have a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: To use `xsl:for-each select="sort(sm:url, (), function($url) { $url/sm:lastmod })"` instead of the `xsl:for-each select="sm:url"` in your code should be easy enough, I am not sure what else you need. Perhaps start by indenting your code, then it will be easier to read.

Comment: I have replaced `xsl:for-each select="sm:url"` with `xsl:for-each select="sort(sm:url, (), function($url) { $url/sm:lastmod })"`, but the XML sitemap goes blank in the browser when I do that, meaning something is going wrong in the XSL stylesheet if I do that. As soon as I undo that change by replacing `xsl:for-each select="sort(sm:url, (), function($url) { $url/sm:lastmod })"` with `xsl:for-each select="sm:url"`, the XML sitemap works again as before.

Comment: Well, browsers support XSLT 1 so you shouldn't claim "I'm using XSL 3.0" if you run the XSLT in the browser, unless you used Saxon-JS 2 which is a library to support that latest version. `<xsl:for-each select="sm:url"><xsl:sort select="sm:lastmod"/>..</xsl:for-each>` is XSLT 1.0 compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, maybe it already worked before and I missed it because I was so frustrated. I have edited my question and corrected it as XSLT 1.0.